# How stop a Mobile Foundation server and/or the container?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

I want to use a Mobile Foundation on Bluemix for development purpose.

In the pricing plan section, I can see that I will have 365h free each month.

There is a way to stop the service from counting in a way to use only 365h or less in a month? (a mount could have up to 720h, right?)

Despite to made two question in a row, there is a way to reduce the size o the container to 256mb instead of 1gb?

Regards,
Bernardo Baumblatt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server wont run correctly with less than 1 GB. The way to not bill after 365 hours is to delete the instance. There is no concept of Start/Stop the Mobile Foundation service

Comment: Hi Chebbi, are you sure about not running correctly below 1GB, the older container with 7.1 run well for development purpose with just 64mb. Furthermore, in documentation and images in creation page shows container's size starting from 64mb.

Comment: @BernardoBaumblatt Thats correct. For the MobileFoundation service on bluemix there is no size supported below 1 GB. If you are referring to the container docs - then yes you can have a container for 64MB - but the container creation in the context of the Mobile foundation bluemix service is 1 GB min.

Answer (score 0):

Despite that there are no start/stop/restart commands in the associated container on the container's list, looking around I found a way to stop the container.

Inside de Mobile Foundation instance's overview page, there is a 'card/painel' with the 'containers in this groups'. Clicking in the desire container, there are a container's detail page where is possible to stop it.

I'm still looking for a way to stop the Mobile Foundation Server's instance it self for a complete answer of my question.

Comment: that is a capability that container groups provide to stop individual nodes. there is no concept of stopping a container group. Also the billing for your hours starts from the moment you click the Start Server and continues till the service instance is deleted.

Comment: The stopped container starts automatically after a while. So, in this case, the best answer is the Chebbi above.